Movie containing a white male who is a geneticist
I vaguely remember dialogue in a movie. This movie has an actor who acts as a geneticist. I only remember his short dialogue. This is what he says.

I am geneticist. I am the one who determines whether you will be born with 2 hands or 2 feet

Note: The dialogue I remember is not 100% the same as the original.
The geneticist is a white man. I think he has blonde/brown hair with side way bangs. He says the dialogue perhaps on a rescue mission. So, the rescuer prioritizes him first.
The movie is around 2000's and in English. It is probably a quite well-known Hollywood movie.

Could it be Red Planet (2000)
Dr. Quinn Burchenal (Tom Sizemore) declares:


“I’m a geneticist: I write code, okay? – A, G, T, P in different combinations – hacking the
    human genome, okay?  I choose what, I choose where...and either your
    kidneys work or you grow a sixth finger. I do that! Now, you spot
    God... 
    ...you let me know. Until then, I'll trust my Ph.Ds".



Thank you for your answer. This seems to be the dialogue. But, I need to rewatch the movie again to make sure.
